# How can I customize BuddyPress pages from inside the Wordpress dashboard?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, content-management-system, buddypress

https://dev.evolutionaryeducation.org/register/

I'm trying to add some padding to the body so the whole form shows up.

I'm trying to add a custom footer as well.

The problem is that everything I do on 'edit page' doesn't do anything at all.

I looked on the BuddyPress website and that hasn't been much help so far.

Please help. I'm working overtime on this site over Christmas Eve and Christmas Day to get this guy's site ready on time. This is the last thing I have to do: set up https://dev.evolutionaryeducation.org/community/

Thanks!